# What's the blending equation of THREE.NormalBlending?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't find it in the document. Could anyone tell me what's the equation?

I thought it is equal to the following `THREE.CustomBlending`:

```
    blending: THREE.CustomBlending,
    blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation,
    blendSrc: THREE.SrcAlphaFactor,
    blendDst: THREE.OneMinusSrcAlphaFactor
```

But I get a different result when I change the material from `NormalBlending` to the above `CustomBlending`.

Here is the [link](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/constants/CustomBlendingEquations) about default `CustomBlending`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looking at the source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/afb0dd4a4937d877c143fe7e9b7ea937c3f79eb5/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLState.js) the various Three.js blending modes are different depending on whether or not the material is marked as using premultiplied alpha or not

So, if the material is considered pre-multiplied then it should be the same as

```
blending: THREE.CustomBlending,
blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation,
blendSrc: THREE.OneFactor,
blendDst: THREE.OneMinusSrcAlphaFactor
```

Otherwise it's

```
blending: THREE.CustomBlending,
blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation,
blendSrc: THREE.SrcAlphaFactor,
blendSrcAlpha: THREE.OneFactor,
blendDst: THREE.OneMinusSrcAlphaFactor
```

```js
"use strict";

const nonPremultipledBlend = {
  blending: THREE.CustomBlending,
  blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation,
  blendSrc: THREE.SrcAlphaFactor,
  blendSrcAlpha: THREE.OneFactor,
  blendDst: THREE.OneMinusSrcAlphaFactor,
};

const premultipledBlend = {
  blending: THREE.CustomBlending,
  blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation,
  blendSrc: THREE.OneFactor,
  blendDst: THREE.OneMinusSrcAlphaFactor,
};


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-1.5, 1.5, 1, -1, -1, 1);
camera.position.z = 1;
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(.5, .5);
[
  { color: 0xFF8080, x: -.6,  y:    0, z: 0.2, },
  { color: 0x008040, x: -.30, y: -.25, z: 0.1, },
  { color: 0x008040, x: -.90, y: -.25, z: 0.1, blend: nonPremultipledBlend, },
  { color: 0xFF8080, x:  .6,  y:    0, z: 0.2, },
  { color: 0x008040, x:  .30, y: -.25, z: 0.1, pre: true, },
  { color: 0x008040, x:  .90, y: -.25, z: 0.1, pre: true, blend: premultipledBlend, },
].forEach(info => {
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: info.color,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: .5,
  });
  if (info.pre) {
    material.premultipliedAlpha = info.pre;
  }
  if (info.blend) {
    Object.assign(material, info.blend);
  }
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);
  mesh.position.x = info.x;
  mesh.position.y = info.y;
  mesh.position.z = info.z;
});
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for always answering my questions!

Comment: According to the alpha compositing equation, the `blendDst` factor should be `DstAlpha * (1 - SrcAlpha)`. But the equation above is only `1 - SrcAlpha`. Why?